# Custom formatter for all levels no longer works in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

In Python2 I use the following class to format all logging levels:

```
class SimpleFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    FORMATS = {
        logging.DEBUG:    "[D][%(module)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(funcName)s} %(message)s",
        logging.INFO:     "%(message)s",
        logging.WARNING:  "[-][%(module)s] %(message)s",
        logging.ERROR:    "[!][%(module)s] %(message)s",
        logging.CRITICAL: "[!][%(module)s] %(message)s",
        'DEFAULT':        "[%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
    }

    def format(self, record):
        self._fmt = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno, self.FORMATS['DEFAULT'])
        return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)


stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler.setFormatter(SimpleFormatter())

log = logging.getLogger('log')
log.addHandler(get_handler('debug.log'))
log.addHandler(stream_handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug("Test from %s", 123)
```

In Python3 this has no effect, what was changed?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Python 3.2` there has been a new [`style` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter).

The code for `logging.Formatter.format` now calls `self.formatMessage`:

```
def formatMessage(self, record):
    return self._style.format(record)
```

The `_style` has its own `_fmt` which you are not setting, and I think that is why you are seeing no change.

I think if you change your `format` to:

```
def format(self, record):
    self._style._fmt = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno, self.FORMATS['DEFAULT'])
    return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
```

You will get the intended output.

You can also compare the logging source code yourself:

[Python 2.7 source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py)

[Python 3.8 source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py)